# Two issues concerning Splitcontainers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-interface, split

I'm designing a GUI using multiple split containers. I have a control which should start at a size of 200 x 200. That control sits in Panel1 of the SplitContainer which should also start at size 200 x 200. I've also set Panel1's MinSize to 200 so as to not get any smaller than 200 pixels high.

My problem comes in setting the SplitterDistance to 200 pixels, as there seems to be some "barrier" that prevents the SplitterDistance from going above a random amount of pixels (71, in this case).

So the SplitterDistance starts at 50. I set it to 200, but it ends up at 71. And I can't figure out why that is... Any suggestions?  Also, this particular SplitContainer only gains a Panel2 at runtime, hence why there is no Panel2 currently...

Here is some relevant code:

```
BetweenPanelContext.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
BetweenPanelContext.Panel1.Size = new Size(200,200);
BetweenPanelContext.SplitterDistance = 200;
BetweenPanelContext.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
BetweenPanelContext.Panel1MinSize = 200;
BetweenPanelContext.Panel1.Controls.Add(context);
.................................................
this.context.Name = "context";
this.context.TabIndex = 0;
this.context.Text = "context";
this.context.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
this.context.Size = new Size(200, 200);
```

---

My second issue is that one of my panels starts at a size that is less than the Panel1MinSize property I've set for it, but if I grab the splitter, then it will jump to the correct size and not let me resize down to what it started as. Why is this? How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: Vertical or Horizontal, `SplitContainer.Orientation`?

Comment: The `SplitterDistance` depends on `SplitContainer.Size` who also depends on the `Form.Size`, if you use `DockStyle.Fill`. This could be the Problem that prevent this Implementation to work.

Comment: This particular SplitContainer is a Horizontal orientation. However, it's nestled inside of another SplitContainer of Vertical orientation.

Comment: Also, the form is maximized in the window, but I'll give it a shot. Thanks for the starting point! It's breaking y brain to think of all these containers :P

Comment: hehe, maybe, you take a look at remarks/example section for `SplitterDistance` on MSDN. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer.splitterdistance.aspx

Comment: There's no option to *not* have a Panel2.  Better start there.

Comment: What I meant was that it only gains a user control to be displayed in Panel2 at run time. I'm making progress though, so thank you both for your help! I appreciate it.